# query sub document in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am trying to query the company name and its admin users.

This is my structure:

```
companies: [
    {
        _id: "generatedComp1Id",
        name: "abc",
        users: [
          { _id: "...", user: "userId1", roles: ["admin"]},
          { _id: "...", user: "userId2", roles: ["user"]}
        ]
    },
    {
        _id: "generatedComp2Id",
        name: "xyz",
        users: [
          { _id: "...", user: "userId3", roles: ["admin"]},
          { _id: "...", user: "userId4", roles: ["admin"]},
          { _id: "...", user: "userId5", roles: ["user"]}
        ]
    }

]
```

I'm trying to query company `name` and admin users for each company given a companyId.

Output:

for company ID of `generatedComp1Id`:

```
{
    name: "abc",
    adminUsers: [
        {user: "userId1"}
    ]
}
```

for company ID of `generatedComp2Id`:

```
{
    name: "xyz",
    adminUsers: [
        {user: "userId3"},
        {user: "userId4"}
    ]
}
```

I tried to do the next thing with no success:

```
[  
   { $match: {_id: ObjectId("generatedComp1Id")}},
   {
        $project: {
            name: 1,
            adminUsers: {
                $filter: {
                    input: "$roles",
                    as: "role",
                    cond: {
                        $eq: ["$$role", "admin"]
                    }
                }                
            }
        }
    }
]
```

In addition, I tried `unwind`:

```
[
  {$unwind:'$users'}, 
  {$match:{'users.roles':{$in:['admin']}}},
  {$group:{_id:'$_id',users:{$push:'$users'}}},
  { $project: { name: 1 } }
  ]
```

Comment: In your `$filter` use the field `users` _instead of_ `roles`. And, in the `cond` check if the `user.roles` has the specific role.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `$filter` to iterate loop of `users` array, check condition for "admin" is in `roles` array
- `$map` to iterate loop of above filtered result and return `user` field

```
[
  { $match: { _id: ObjectId("generatedComp1Id") } },
  {
    $project: {
      name: 1,
      adminUsers: {
        $map: {
          input: {
            $filter: {
              input: "$users",
              as: "role",
              cond: { $in: ["admin", "$$role.roles"] }
            }
          },
          in: { user: "$$this.user" }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/0-P3QWzsrIH)